# Why a Faiss index works on macOS but not on Docker (TypeError in method)?

Tags: python, faiss

I'm trying to search for vectors using [Faiss](https://github.com/facebookresearch/faiss) and access them through an API. All my packages are installed with Conda.

```py
def get_similar_posts(embeddings: list[float]) -> list[str]:
    toSearch = np.array([embeddings])
    toSearch.reshape(1, len(embeddings))

    k = 30

    D, I = index.search(toSearch, k)

    print(D)

    return []
```

This snippet works perfectly fine on my MacBook Air M1. But as soon as I try to run it using Docker, Faiss returns this:

```
ERROR:    Exception in ASGI application
Traceback (most recent call last):
[...]
  File "/app/main.py", line 25, in read_root
    print(get_similar_posts(embed))
  File "/app/faiss_index.py", line 28, in get_similar_posts
    D, I = index.search(toSearch, k)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/faiss/__init__.py", line 322, in replacement_search
    self.search_c(n, swig_ptr(x), k, swig_ptr(D), swig_ptr(I))
  File "/opt/conda/envs/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/faiss/swigfaiss.py", line 7722, in search
    return _swigfaiss.IndexIDMap_search(self, n, x, k, distances, labels)
TypeError: in method 'IndexIDMap_search', argument 3 of type 'faiss::IndexIDMapTemplate< faiss::Index >::component_t const *'
```

I have tried to rebuild the index again using Float32, but it didn't make any difference. Digging through the Faiss code didn't give me any clues either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed it.

First, as stated [in the GitHub](https://github.com/facebookresearch/faiss/issues/1118#issuecomment-591991531), I had to set the type of my array to `float32`. But that wasn't enough. Faiss was still returning an error. I had to make sure `k` was an integer.

Here is the full snippet:

```py
def get_similar_posts(embeddings: list[float]) -> list[str]:
    toSearch = np.array([embeddings]).astype("float32")
    toSearch.reshape(1, len(embeddings))

    k = 30
    k = int(k)

    D, I = index.search(toSearch, k)

    print(D)

    return []
```

I don't really know the reasons, but it's fixed.